# C++ - Kruskal algorithm STL

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, kruskals-algorithm

Based on video I wrote Kruskal's algorithm. But I have "little" problem - instead of finding lowest weights it finds me highest. This may sound funny, but I can't find where I made mistake.

```
collection::collection(int vert){ coll = new SNode[vert]; }
collection::~collection(){}
void collection::Create(int vert)
{
    coll[vert].up = vert;
    coll[vert].rank = 0;
}
int collection::Find(int vert)
{
    /*if (coll[vert].up != vert) coll[vert].up = Find(coll[vert].up);
    return coll[vert].up;*/
    if (coll[vert].up == vert) return coll[vert].up;
    else Find(coll[vert].up);
}
void collection::Union(graf::Edges e)
{
    int home, dest;
    home = Find(e.v1);
    dest = Find(e.v2);
    if (home != dest){
        if (coll[home].rank > coll[dest].rank){ coll[dest].up = home; }
        else if (coll[home].rank < coll[dest].rank){ coll[home].up = dest; }
        else{
            coll[home].up = dest;             
            //if (coll[home].rank == coll[dest].rank) 
                coll[dest].rank++;
        }
    }
}
```

And main algorithm. Weights are kept in two dimensional matrix called 'weightmat'. Vertex is quantity of vertices, Edges is struct with variables v1,v2,weight. Using this struct I create array of edges. :

```
collection newcollection(vertex);

        struct CompareMat{
            bool operator()(Edges &node1, Edges &node2){
                if (node1.weight < node2.weight) return true;
                else return false;
            }
        };

        priority_queue<Edges, vector<Edges>, CompareMat> EdgesQueue;
        Edges temp;
        Edges* edges = new Edges[edge];
        Edges* MSTTree = new Edges[vertex-1];

        for (int i = 0; i < vertex; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < vertex; j++)
            {
                if (nbhmat[i][j] != 0){
                    edges[i].v1 = i;
                    edges[i].v2 = j;
                    edges[i].weight = weightmat[i][j];
                }
            }
            EdgesQueue.push(edges[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < vertex; i++){
            newcollection.Create(i);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < vertex; i++)          
        {
            do
            {
                temp = EdgesQueue.top();             
                EdgesQueue.pop();                    
            } while (newcollection.Find(temp.v1) == newcollection.Find(temp.v2));
            MSTTree[i - 1] = temp;
            newcollection.Union(temp);
        }

        cout << endl << endl << "Kruskal's algorithm for matrix:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertex - 1; i++){
            cout << MSTTree[i].v1 << " " << MSTTree[i].v2 << " weight " << MSTTree[i].weight << endl;
        }
```

Comment: Add some printout code. Run it on a small graph. See what decisions it's making.

Comment: Oooh... Now I see. That was really simply mistake. I should create bigger array and i did wrong assign to edges[i] in for loop. Topic closed, problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

`priority_queue` has the *biggest* element on its top (yes, with the comparator class being equivalent to `less`), but you need the smallest edges first. You need to invert your `CompareMat::operator()` comparison.

Two more notes.

Firstly, in `CompareMat::operator()` you can return comparison result directly:

```
//return node1.weight < node2.weight; // your version
return node1.weight > node2.weight;  // correct version
```

Secondly, why do you need a priority queue? A simple sort will suffice, because you do not seem to change your edges.